# Formatting number in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, apex

```
 <apex:inputField type="number" value="{!varA}"/>
```

This is the code `varA` is defined in the apex controller now the value I want to show of it is 1 only integer but it is displaying 1.00 can you tell me how I can drop that decimal in showing the value?

I tried `value={!ROUND(varA)}` but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using inputField to display it, the format is determined by the definition of the custom field varA. Can you change the custom field definition to not specify decimal positions?

Also you can try to use JavaScript for modifying view:

```
<apex:form id="formBlock">
<apex:inputText value="{!withDec}" id="withDec"/>
</apex:form>

 <script>
 if('{!withDec}' != '' || '{!withDec}' != null){
    var itm = '{!withDec}';
    document.getElementById('{!$Component.formBlock.withDec}').value = Math.floor(itm);
 }     
 </script>
```

Comment: I do not want to specify it in definition 
Can you please tell me the way with visualforce and angularjs only ?

Comment: Actually, you don't need angular for this, I updated my answer and you can similarly modify value on Visualforce page

Comment: Is It ok if i don't use form ?
Thanks for the reply

Comment: As I remember, if you use apex:inputText and apex:inputField you should wrap it in apex:form tag.

Comment: Yeah sorry i forgot that
n it is still not working for me i dont know why

Comment: I have the value stored in object 
and i am using it with the Page block and ng-repeat also 
now if i write script after closing of form and all 
it won't be able to get the value... 
can you tell me how to use it in this case?

Comment: even for variable its still showing one decimal place 
i want it that if value is 5.000 then it should display 5 only @Last Khajiit